# Integer Picker to select in swiftui xcode

Tags: xcode, swiftui, qr-code

I am making a project with qr code generator and i don't know how to use integer with picker and i want to ask what code did i missed in the function and the view. does any expert know how to solve it, thank you for the help.

my code:

```
@State private var sSecond = Int()
@State var navigated = false
let Second = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"]
var body: some View {
        Form{
            Section { 
                VStack{
                    Picker(selection: $sSecond, label: Text("Select Seconds"))
                    {
                        ForEach(0 ..< Second.count) {
                            index in Text(self.Second[index]).tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: Generate(Second: $sSecond), isActive: self.$navigated)
{
    Text("Complete")
}
        }
```

Function:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

struct Generate: View {
    @State var second = Int()
    let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
    let cont = CIContext()
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: imageGenerate(second))
            .interpolation(.none)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150, alignment: .center)
    }
    func imageGenerate(second: Int)-> UIImage {
        let data = Data(second)
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        if let qr = filter.outputImage {
            if let qrImage = cont.createCGImage(qr, from: qr.extent){
                return UIImage(cgImage: qrImage)
            }
        }
        return UIImage(systemName: "xmark") ?? UIImage()
    }
}
```

How Can I Show 10 in qr code, thats what i expected in this questions

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question: Picker on Int goes like this:

```
struct PickerInt: View {
    
    let secondsArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60] // Int instead of String
    @State private var sSecond: Int = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        Form{
            Picker(selection: $sSecond, label: Text("Select Seconds"))
            {
                ForEach(secondsArray, id: \.self) { sec in
                    Text("\(sec)").tag(sec)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about the function?

Comment: only one question / answer per post

Comment: This was the correct answer. Thank you ChrisR